# How much dough (by weight) to make to fit my bread tin

Tags: baking, bread, dough

My bread loaf tin does not have any labels on it (e.g. 1lb, 2lbs etc.).  It does not have a lid.  It is also not squarely shaped, so calculating the volume by its dimensions is not clear.

Instead, I determined that it holds 2,100 grams of water, when filled to the brim.  Based on this, how much dough, in grams, should I make to fit the tin?  If it is insightful, I am making white bread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1g of water = 1ml = 1 cubic centimeter, so 2100g of water is 2100 cubic centimeters. Converting that into cubic inches gives us 128 cubic inches, which equates to a 1.25 pound pan. So, use a 1lb recipe and increase it by 25%.